# Nodestore and relationshipstore on different locations/directories/drives

Tags: neo4j

I want to have the nodestore, relationshipstore, and property stores on different drives. Is there a configuration value that I can modify to achieve this?

The only thing so far that I have seen is the neo_store configuration, but that only changes the location of all store files relative to the store_dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any config setting for this. However you can shut down your database and move the respective files to a separate drive and place a symlink into the the store directory.

N.B. I have not tested this setup myself.

Comment: Not sure what your intention for such a setup is. With SSD drives I don't see a big benefit of distribution the store files to seperates disks.

Comment: Maximum read/write performance per disk, if I have the properties on disk, and the nodes and relationships on another I could expect that the data contained in those nodes would be going through a different I/O channel that those that are doing traversals (rough example).

Comment: if you see significant better throughput by moving files to seperate drives, please publish your findings.